# How to click only one cell at a time like radio button in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to select one cell and on click of them change image. But when I click on other cell its image also got change.
[image]

As in image I can select all Full,Partial and None.I want to select only one at a time like radio button.
My code is like this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   FPNTableViewCell *cell = (FPNTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   cell.circleimg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"CircleClick.png"];
}
```

I am using Custom tableview. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tableview method

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}
```

for selecting.

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}
```

for unselect.

Answer (score 1):

1. Initialise an Int (top of the controller Eg: int i=0;)
2. tableview didselect method assign the selected index to that int
   EG: i = indexpath.row
3. Cellforrowindex method check the i with indexpath. Based on that you can use the image

Comment: I want to change the image just like radio button.

Comment: @Muju you can. You have to use two images. checked and unchecked. So based on the cell selection you can change the image. But you have to reload the tableview every time (didselect method). You image handling part should be in the cellforrow index method